# Build child menu based on values selected in parent multiple select list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to construct a second select list based on options selected in my first select list (which is a multiple).  However my append is adding multples.  My alert returns

1st alert 1

2nd alert 1,5

3rd alert 1.5,7

I need the append to happen for the very last option selected.

```
$('#firstselect').change(function(){
       alert('id ' + $(this).val());
        $('#secondselect').append('<option value=' + $(this).find(':selected:last').val() +'>' + $(this).find(':selected:last').text()) + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but you don't need to append the options indivdually or construct them manually, just clone them and exchange the html of your second `<select>`

```
$('#firstselect').change(function(){
    var cloned = $(this).find(':selected').clone();
    $('#secondselect').html(cloned);
});
```

This will add all selected options in the original order. Of course, you might want them inserted in the order they were selected. That's a bit more tricky, since you have to keep track of what was selected when and also what was actually deselected, but here is a solution for that too:

```
var last_selected;
$('#altfirstselect').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    var cloned = selected.not(last_selected).clone();
    if(last_selected) { 
        var to_remove = last_selected.not(selected);
        to_remove.each(function(){
            $('#altsecondselect').find('[value='+$(this).val()+']').remove();
        });
    }
    $('#altsecondselect').append(cloned);
    last_selected = selected;
});
```

I created a fiddle, where you can see both solutions in action and see how they work differently based on the order of your selection: http://jsfiddle.net/xu333zxs/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. This has been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could just remove them all then add them all again each time. No big deal

```
$('#firstselect').change(function(){
        $('#secondselect option').remove();
        $('#secondselect').append('<option value=' + $(this).(':selected').val() +'>' + $(this).find(':selected').text()) + '</option>';
});
```